# How to call a function inside chrome/plug-in from html page?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am developing one Firefox plug-in. In that, I am using sidebar and I am having an iFrame element within that with the source content from a HTML page.

Now, I want to call a JavaScript function which is inside the 'chrome' (i.e. inside the plug-in) by an onClick() event on the HTML page, loaded in the sidebar.

Is it possible? Please help me in this.

The main aim is to highlight the context in the main browser window similar to that present in the HTML page loaded in the sidebar.

Thank you.

Comment: I *think* that the only way this would be possible would be for your plugin to add code (like, a function with some fixed name attached to the `window` object) upon page load. However somebody else might know a better trick!

Comment: I know that the Firefox/chrome plugin FireBug allows access via javascript to console.log(), which loads data into the plugin, so it's possible... since both browser's plugins are re-named zip files it shouldn't be too hard to get the source code to figure out how they did it.

Comment: This might help. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages

Comment: Thank you MatrixFrog.
It helped me to extent.